# save a belongsTo relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-6

I have a classic one-to-many relationships, and I am trying to save the model of the belongsTo side.

The 2 models have these relationships:

```
// Model myModel
function domicile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Address', 'domicile_id');
}

// Model Address
function myModels()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\MyModel', 'domicile_id');
}
```

This is what I am tryng to do to save it:

```
$myModel->domicile()->save($my_array);
```

With this code I get the error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::save()

if I use this code (without the brackets):

```
$myModel->domicile->save($my_array);
```

I do not get any error but the model is not saved.
I know there is the method `associate`, but I need to update an existent record, not to save a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `save` function, in order to save a belongsTo relationships you have to use the `fill` function.

In this way:

```
$myModel->domicile->fill($my_array);
$myModel->domicile->save();
```

Comment: You must use save() for model observers instead of associate. That caused an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Because `$myModel->domicile()->save($my_array);` is totally different to `$myModel->domicile->save($my_array);` :

1. `$myModel->domicile()` will produce a `BelongsTo` object, doesn't support the `save` because `save` is a method of `HasMany` instances, instead for `BelongsTo` instances you should use `associate(YourModel)`
2. `$myModel->domicile` will produce a `Model` object  of the associated element, which support the `save(array)` method, but that array is a `options` array, as api says https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_save

So in other words, if you have a one (address) to many (domicile) relation, if you want to associate to the address one or many domiciles, you have to use `save` or `saveMany` (https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html#method_save), instead if you want to associate to a domicile a address, you should use `associate` (https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.html#method_associate)... keep in mind that if you want to do this, you should call the properties with the brackets, in order to have back a `HasMany` object or a `BelongsTo` object, and not a Model or a Collection (which you will get if you call the properties without the brackets)

Comment: So why my model is not saved?

Comment: I do not need to save another instance, I need to update an existent record. That's why I can not use the associate function

Comment: @GiacomoM check now

Answer (score 2):

You must use `associate()` + `save()` in order to store a BelongsTo relationship:

```
$myModel->domicile()->associate($domicile);
$myModel->save();
```

See [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships)